# Android: Int stays the same

Tags: android, math, integer

i feel dumb for asking this but i have been fighting with this for a day now and i can't seem to get it working.

So my problem is I want to keep adding 1 to and integer and make it go like ;

```
1+1=2
2+1=3
```

That it keeps updating the Integer I have this now;

```
int val = 1;
int g = 1;

val = g + val;
```

But it keeps saying its 2 how come?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete example -- what you gave here isn't sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Only because 1+1 = 2. No other reason.

Comment: Please post the entire function.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev but what about in large cases of 1?

Comment: My mom, told me it is always true. I believe her :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you put all of your code in your click handler. Instead, put the variable declaration/initialization in the class level and only your addition code in your click handler. Rough code as follows:

```
public YourActivity extends Activity {
    int val = 1;
    int g = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ... //find button in here
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                val = g + val;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you keep setting it to 1. Initialize it outside the loop.

Comment: If this psychic debug turns out to be true you deserve a medal :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = 1;
int g = 1;
```

The next line:

```
val = g + val;
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
val = 1 + 1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
val = 2;
```

Not sure what you would expect here...

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = 1; int g = 1;  val = g + val;
```

Will always evaluate to 2.  Because what happens is you take the value in `g` which is 1 and the value in `val` which is 1.  This produces the sum of 2.  You then take 2 and assign it to the variable `val` (which previously was initialized to 1).

1+1 will always be 2 (in Integer mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

> So my problem is I want to keep adding 1 to and integer and make it go like ;

```
1+1=2
2+1=3
```

I'm guessing you want to do something like this, to produce your output a given number of times.

```
int timesToLoop = 10;
int summedUp = 0;
for (int i=0; i < timesToLoop; i++)
{
    summedUp = i + 1;
    System.out.println(i + " + " + "1 = " + summedUp);
}
```

Comment: No, i'm trying to make an auto increase number everytime i click a button

Comment: @Lars Wesseling so... why not increment the number when the buttons pressed?